# Induced flows on $S^2$

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, spheres

I am referring to [this article (pp. 437) about FitzHugh-Nagumo.](http://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1984-286-02/S0002-9947-1984-0760971-6/S0002-9947-1984-0760971-6.pdf)

Consider the ODE system 
$$
u'=v,~~~~~v'=-cv-f(u)+w,~~~~~w'=(-(\epsilon / c)(u-\gamma w),
$$
where $f(u)=u(u-a)(1-u),~a<\frac{1}{2}$ and constants $\gamma, \epsilon$ are positive.

Let $S_{\epsilon}=(u_{\epsilon},v_{\epsilon},w_{\epsilon})$ be a solution.

Consider the variational equations
$$
\delta u'=\delta v,~~~~~\delta v'=-c\delta v-f'(u_{\epsilon})\delta u+\delta w,~~~~~\delta w'=-(\epsilon / c)(\delta u-\gamma\delta w)~~~~~~~(*)
$$

and the system linearised at the point $U_1=(u_1,v_1,w_1)$ with $\epsilon=0$:
$$
\delta u'=\delta v,~~~~~\delta v'=-c\delta v-f'(u_1)\delta u + \delta w,~~~~~\delta w'=0.~~~~~~~(**)
$$

Now, there is a part (p. 437 below) that I do not understand, I cite it:

> > Because they are linear, both $(*)$ and $(**)$ induce flows on $S^2$ by equating two vectors in $\mathbb{R}^3\setminus\left\{0\right\}$ if one is a positive multiple of the other. The flow of $(**)$ is qualitatively the same as the linearisation at rest. It has one unstable subspace and two stable ones. Let these be spans of the eigenvectors $X_1$ (unstable), $X_2$ and $X_3$.

(1.) Could you please explain me in which way $(*)$ and $(**)$ induce flows on $S^2$?

(2.) Why is the flow induced by $(**)$ qualitative the same as the linearisation at rest (what does that mean)?

(3.) Which subspaces/ eigenvectors are meant?

Would be thankful for any help. Especially understanding how the flow is meant would be essential, I think.

Comment: **Always** put a link to the article or book that you are reading and that you are asking about.

Comment: Allright, I added the link at the top of my post.